# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.3.4.0,

Tags: assembly-binding-redirect, multitargeting

I've seen so many posts around this, followed them, but I can't figure out my situation so can I ask for help:

I have a .Net Framework 4.7.2 Web Form Application that references two multi-targeted library assemblies, which both include the same version.

My web app references the Nuget Package System.Net.Http, Version=4.3.4.0, as do the other 43 projects in my solution, all referenced by the main Web App.

Those two multi-targeted libraries do not reference System.Net.Http of any version.

When I compile, I see a project reference of System.Net.Http v 4.2.0.0 added (probably from the .Net Framework 4.7.2 library itself)

I have an assembly bindingRedirect in my web config for 4.2.0.0 and newVersion of 4.3.4.0

However, when I compile, what ends up in the bin output folder says its 'Product version' and 'File version' is 4.7.3062.0,

so then I end up with the runtime exception:

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

I just don't know where that output folder version is even from because the NuGet version for .Net 4.7.2 only goes as high as 4.3.4.0.

It didn't work if I make a redirect to the 4.7.3062.0 version, and says it can't find that version

How can I get the correct 4.3.4.0 version to end up in the bin output folder so that the binding redirect can find it? Well, is that even correct, as the package directory for 4.3.4, in the \System.Net.Http.4.3.4\lib\net46 directory has version 4.6.26907.01 (??)

Comment: does your binding redirect changes when you regenerate them again?

Comment: I didn't think to check that - I don't think so. In my two multi-target libs, I do have  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
and <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType> so do I need these in the projects that consume these libs?

Comment: No - in web forms apps, the redirects are in web.config and it is never updated. but it does say:     <Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.4\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference> So what's with the 4.1.1.3 ??

Comment: If you have set autogenerate of binding redirects - you need to manually copy them from your bin folder to your web.config in your solution. So replace everything in web.config with new generated binding redirects in your bin.

Comment: and your <Private> attribute should be removed I think

Comment: oh! ok, I'll give that a go!